# How can I create a json file for API calls?

Tags: php, json

I want to parse all of the returned values from a MySQL database into a JSON file. So I wrote my php side like this:

```
foreach ($Posts->Show() as $Key => $Post) {
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Id"]=$Post['Post_Id'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Url"] = "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=" . $Post['Post_Url'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Name"] = $Post['Post_Name'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Date"] = $Post['Post_Date'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Author"] = $Post['Post_Author'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Image"] = "https://eastcloud.ir/" . $Post['Post_Image'];
    $Data ['POST'][$Post['Post_Id']]["Tags"] = "https://eastcloud.ir/" . $Post['Post_Image'];
    $ID++;
}
```

The given json is something like this:

```
POST
17
{
    Id  "17"
    Url "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=Simplist-Documentations"
    Name    "Simplist Documentations"
    Date    "23 May, 2018"
    Author  "Milad"
    Image   "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png"
    Tags    "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png"
}
```

The loop will continue getting value and parsing them into JSON (The JSON file is available [here](https://eastcloud.ir/Blog.json)) but if I want to use the given JSON  here on [Json2Sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) it tells invalid JSON file given.
What is the solution? How can I create a JSON from my database values with PHP?

Comment: You showed just loop of gathering data, not how you make json. And it's invalid. Keys must be enclosed with double-quote, then `:` and key-value pairs except last must end with `,` : `{"Id": "17", "Url": "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=Simplist-Documentations"}`. Best way is to use `json_encode($Data)`

Comment: Something like this:
`$fp = fopen('Blog.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($Data));
fclose($fp);`

Comment: The generated JSON is valid. What is your *precise* question? Is it about `__invalid_type__…`? Then why not mention it?!)

Comment: The problem is [here](http://json2csharp.com/) when I give this JSON to make its related C# classess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method?

```
foreach ($Posts->Show() as $Key => $Post) {
    $Data['POST'][] = [
        $Post['Post_Id'] = [
            "Id" => $Post['Post_Id'],
            "Url" => "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=" . $Post['Post_Url'],
            "Name" => $Post['Post_Name'],
            "Date" => $Post['Post_Date'],
            "Author" => $Post['Post_Author'],
            "Image" => "https://eastcloud.ir/" . $Post['Post_Image'],
            "Tags" => "https://eastcloud.ir/" . $Post['Post_Image'],
        ],
    ];
    $ID++;
}

// here is your json from db fetching loop
$json = json_encode($Data);
```

upd 1.0

Please check this JSON, which I generated based on your

```
{
    "POST" : [
        {
        "Id": "17",
        "Url": "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=Simplist-Documentations",
        "Name": "Simplist Documentations",
        "Date": "23 May, 2018",
        "Author": "Milad",
        "Image": "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png",
        "Tags": "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png"
        },
        {
        "Id": "18",
        "Url": "https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=angular-2-vs-react",
        "Name": "انگیولار ۲ در مقابل ری‌اکت",
        "Date": "23 May, 2018",
        "Author": "Milad",
        "Image": "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/432644.png",
        "Tags": "https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/432644.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Reponse from json2csharp

```
public class POST
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<POST> POST { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sure.
Also, I generated a JSON file [here](https://eastcloud.ir/Blog.json) but the JSON is not valid to use on [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: @MiladXandi Please check my upd 1.0. I've generated some similar array using Laravel and then used it for your tool and seems get a correct response from the json2shart service. Structure is a bit different, there are not lead `Post_ID` and all objects are wrapped in `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) for creating json. It is not the best way to create it
manually.

To understand what is wrong with your output, the correct JSON format of your data should look like this:

```
{
    "Id":"17",
    "Url":"https://eastcloud.ir/Blog?=Simplist-Documentations",
    "Name":"Simplist Documentations",
    "Date":"23 May, 2018",
    "Author":"Milad",
    "Image":"https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png",
    "Tags":"https://eastcloud.ir/Content/Shared/Posts/SimplistV2.png"
}
```

Take a closer look at the **quotation marks** and the **double dots** and **comma** after each not the last line.

Comment: Even if I send those values directly for encoding, the result is not valid for json2sharp.
[here is the given result](https://eastcloud.ir/Belog.json)

Comment: @MiladXandi Actually it's valid JSON and your json2csharp works fine

Comment: The output you have given is an array, not a JSON.

Comment: @MiladXandi yep I just used the result from your link on json2csharp and it generates code, no errors. Perhaps it's not the code you wanted, but that's not the same thing as saying it isn't valid. If you're wondering, it creates classes called "invalid type" because you're using numbers as property names in your JSON...you can't make a C# class whose name starts with a number. Perhaps you should tell us what C# you were hoping to generate.

Comment: @Diceros now I am editing this page to get a valid result

Answer (score -1):

You can use json_encode() data from database